# Behavior of rm - how to prevent deletion of mounted points contents

Tags: backup, rm

There is a way to prevent `rm` from deleting mount points?

For example, if I have /mnt/backup mounted externally and someone runs `rm -rf /` I know it will delete the backup contents.

My solution is to umount /mnt/backup after the backup concludes.

Comment: There's one more thing that doen't seem to have been mentioned in the answers.  Properly securing your system accounts is the first part in ensuring the system's security.  On most distributions, direct access to a root account is blocked for that reason, preventing many security issues and accidents.

Comment: An alternative to completely unmounting it would be to `mount -o remount,ro` it, to mount it as merely read only, after the backup concludes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rm --one-file-system` should do the trick.

```
   --one-file-system
          when removing a hierarchy recursively, skip any directory that
          is on a file system different from that of the corresponding
          command line argument
```

Source: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rm.1.html

Comment: I think OP is concerned about accidents and possibly about malicious damage, so this won't really help...

Comment: @derobert He could alias `rm` to `rm --one-file-system`

Comment: Derobert this is true, but i think i can put an alias on that, on the /etc/bash.bashrc to help with accidents.

Comment: Yes, that might help with accidents, but not against attacks. (Also we have a question somewhere on why aliasing rm to `rm -i` is considered a bad idea... a lot of that probably applies to this too)

Comment: Yes if the guy have access to the terminal as root you cant do nothing about. Maybe if the storage downloads the server....

Answer (score 5):

Best practice would be to not only unmount but additionally disconnect the backup.

You presumably expect your backup to protect you in case (for example) someone accidentally downloads a cryptolocker. Or someone breaks in (compromises) your system. Or a weird system crash that corrupts filesystems. Or a lightning surge that fries all your electronic devices that are plugged in. Someone/something that does that is limited by:

- permissions, if they only obtain access to a non-root account (your backups should only be writable by a dedicated account) Consider also things like snapshots, where you can make the snapshot only touchable by root, but leave the current backup accessible to the user. Or make the snapshot read-only.
- unmounted filesystem, again if non-root (presuming something like udisks doesn't allow it to be mounted). This does almost always protect against the weird crash, though.
- the laws of physics, if you disconnect the drive

You have to pick which threats you are going to protect against, balanced against the cost/inconvenience.

Also keep in mind the risk of unwanted disclosure, not just the risk of unwanted data loss. Also you can have multiple backups to combine advantages. E.g., maybe every month you switch USB hard drives—now you have the convenience of it always being connected, but if someone roots the machine and wipes it, you have last month's backup safe and sound.

Comment: The two answers are very good so +1 for you. The first one is good for preventing accidents and the second one very good for preventing attacks.